# Send an email with query results on a scheduled basis (Everyday morning 9AM):

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

My head of engineering, product and other departments wants a daily email sent out of **Shared queries** or particular Work Item query like Bug, Task, Epic to know the status of Work Items.

Is there any extensions available to send the query results on a schedule basis?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it through Schedule pipeline to call APIs to get result and send mail programming.

You also could build a app (e.g. service application, powershell job) to call REST APIs to get necessary result and send mail programming.

Related REST API:

[Wiql - Query By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

[Work Items - Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for this purpose - [Scheduled Work Item Query](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery):

> The Goal of this extension was to keep as much functionality as
> possible inside Azure DevOps / Team Foundation Server. We have opted
> to realize this by using a standard Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps /
> Team Foundation Server as our "Scheduling" Engine.
>
> The actual functionality is realized as a Build Pipeline Task called
> "Scheduled Work Item Query". This task executes a query that is saved
> in either the "My Queries" or "Shared Queries" folders, and sends the
> results by e-mail using either SendGrid or standard SMTP.